# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord include queries happen while not specifing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, include

Whenever i try to call this:

```
  @ships = Ship.find(:all,
                    :conditions => {:sold => params[:sold]},
                    :order => "ship.id desc")
```

From this model:

```
class Ship < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'ship'

    self.inheritance_column = :ruby_type
    belongs_to :brand, :class_name => 'Brand', :foreign_key => :brand    
    belongs_to :fuel, :class_name => 'Fuel', :foreign_key => :fuel    
    has_many :ship_pictures, :class_name => 'ShipPicture'
    has_many :reservations, :class_name => 'Reservation'    
end
```

I end up with these queries:

```
  Ship Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ship".* FROM "ship" WHERE "ship"."sold" = 'false' ORDER BY ship.id desc
  Brand Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "brand".* FROM "brand" WHERE "brand"."name" = 'Percedes' LIMIT 1
  Fuel Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "fuel".* FROM "fuel" WHERE "fuel"."name" = 'Air' LIMIT 1
  ShipPicture Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ship_picture".* FROM "ship_picture" WHERE "ship_picture"."ship_id" = 2
  Brand Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "brand".* FROM "brand" WHERE "brand"."name" = 'Volksship' LIMIT 1
  Fuel Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "fuel".* FROM "fuel" WHERE "fuel"."name" = 'Nuclear Reactor' LIMIT 1
  ShipPicture Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ship_picture".* FROM "ship_picture" WHERE "ship_picture"."ship_id" = 1
```

Why is this happening? I'm not calling :include or anything like that? I want to join ship_pictures and only get the first result of that join.

And a second thing: What is considered to be better: the symbolic or method way?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the symbolic or method way". Are you talking about the difference between `Ship.find(:all, :conditions => {...}, :include => ...)` and `Ship.where(...).include(...)`?

Comment: Also, and you may have a reason for wanting to do this, but you don't need to specify `:class_name` for associations where the class can be inferred, e.g. `has_many :ship_pictures` will automatically use `ShipPicture`.

Comment: Yes i did ment between `Ship.find(:all, :conditions => {...}, :include => ...)` and `Ship.where(...).include(...)`

Comment: Ok thanks tristanm. I used a reverse script since i already had the database structure, but i've removed it now.

Comment: To answer your question on which is better, definitely use the new chainable methods over the old-style `find(:all, :conditions...)` API. I think the old API is deprecated as of Rails 3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be lazy loading at play here. If lazy loading was being used I'd expect to only see three queries for `Brand`, `Fuel` and `ShipPicture` with SQL like:

```
WHERE "ship_picture"."ship_id" IN [1,2]
```

Do you have any other code in your `Ship` model that calls any of those associations?

If your finder above is from a controller, you might be calling `ship.fuel`, `ship.brand` or `ship.ship_pictures` somewhere in your view. This is the usual cause of N+1 queries. If it's not from a controller then it is most likely to be some other code that's being run on the results of the query.

Comment: I can't believe i was so blind >:(. I was calling render :json => @ships.to_json(:include => :ship_pictures) sigh. Thanks for the fast and good awnser!